# I need to check if table has been inserted a new record from a vb.net service application

Tags: vb.net, sql-server-2008

I have 2 SQL DB, in one of the DB I have a table with a trigger that when a new record is inserted, insert a new record in the other Db in log table. I have running a vb.net service application and I need to know / check if the log table had a new record to make actions (example: send email). Which will be the best way to do this? I'm running MS SQL 2008 on a Windows Server 2008.

Answer (score 0):

Why not make use of master database's `sp_send_dbmail` stored procuedure to send email from inside of the trigger body? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190307.aspx.

You will have to create a profile.
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187605.aspx

Comment: Thank for your answer. I need to send in attach a pdf file with logo and data. I'm using the reporting services for this, and couldn't find how to do it with sp_send_mail.

Comment: Donald, is there any way to run a report from reporting services and save the file as pdf from t-sql? thank you in advance for your answer.

Comment: That I am not sure of. I don't believe the PDF rendering that SSRS provides will be of any use at that level.